# How do I capture SYN tcpdump packets within a Linux server?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp, tcpdump

I'm trying to process all server connections using tcpdump using python and it was working very well using this command:

```
tcpdump -tttt -nn 'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn'
```

Here is what it captures:

- Any connections to and from the server from another machine
- Running on the box, it will log a telnet to port 22

Here is what it doesn't:

- if I run ssh localhost
- anytime any server (or most processes) on the machine syn's to a listen port      on the same machine

So I'm getting all traffic from the outside in and inside out, but nothing that is happening withing the machine.

I think I got some of the flags wrong, but I'm not sure what.  Any ideas?  I'm simply trying to monitor server connection activity inside a machine, but only getting a log when it's external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-i any` to capture data of all interfaces, including loopback ("localhost to localhost")

Answer (score 0):

Connections on localhost will be going over the `lo` interface. Try using the `-i any` option to make it listen to all network interfaces.

Comment: Presumably you meant `-i any`, as this is Linux rather than OS X.  (Either `-i any` or `-i all` works on newer versions of OS X, with Apple's tcpdump and libpcap, although they just document `-i all`.)

Comment: @GuyHarris Nice catch. I probably looked at the manpage on the wrong machine. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude your own IP (the ssh client IP) by

```
    tcpdump -tttt -nn 'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn && ! host <ssh-client-ip>'
```

For example, if you ssh from 10.2.3.4, then the command should be

```
    tcpdump -tttt -nn 'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn && ! host 10.2.3.4'
```

Hope it helps.